# How to populate second dropdown based on selection of first dropdown using jQuery/AJAX and PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a dynamic set of dropdown boxes, using jQuery/AJAX and PHP/MySQL.  The first dropdown box will be populated when the page loads based on values from a database.  The second dropdown box should display a set of values based on the selection from the first dropdown box.  I know there have been similar questions asked on here before, but I haven't found a solution that matches my scenario.

My query to generate a JSON encoded list of values for the second drop down is functioning, but I am having issues populating it into the actual dropdown form element.  Any ideas on where I'm going wrong.

Javascript:

```
<script>
$().ready(function() {

    $("#item_1").change(function () {   

      var group_id = $(this).val();

       $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "../../db/groups.php?item_1_id=" + group_id, 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                //Clear options corresponding to earlier option of first dropdown
                $('select#item_2').empty(); 
                $('select#item_2').append('<option value="0">Select Option</option>');
                //Populate options of the second dropdown
                $.each( data.subjects, function(){    
                    $('select#item_2').append('<option value="'+$(this).attr('group_id')+'">'+$(this).attr('name')+'</option>');
                });
                $('select#item_2').focus();
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('select#item_2').empty();
                $('select#item_2').append('<option value="0">Loading...</option>');
            },
            error: function(){
                $('select#item_2').attr('disabled', true);
                $('select#item_2').empty();
                $('select#item_2').append('<option value="0">No Options</option>');
            }
        })  

    }); 
});

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<label id="item_1_label" for="item_1" class="label">#1:</label>
<select id="item_1" name="item_1" />
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php
        $sth = $dbh->query ("SELECT id, name, level 
                             FROM groups
                             WHERE level = '1'
                             GROUP by name
                             ORDER BY name");                                   
        while ($row = $sth->fetch ()) { 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>'."\n";       
        }
     ?>
</select>

<label id="item_2_label" for="item_2" class="label">#2:</label>
<select id="item_2" name="item_2" />                        
</select>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

require_once('../includes/connect.php');        

$item_1_id = $_GET['item_1_id'];

$dbh = get_org_dbh($org_id);

$return_arr = array();

$sth = $dbh->query ("SELECT id, name, level 
                     FROM groups
                     WHERE level = '2'
                     AND parent = $item_1_id
                     GROUP by name
                     ORDER BY name");   

while ($row = $sth->fetch ()) { 

    $row_array = array("name" => $row['name'], 
                       "id" => $row['id']); 

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);     
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

Sample JSON Output:

```
[{"name":"A","id":"0"},{"name":"B","id":"1"},{"name":"C","id":"2"}]
```

Comment: Are you getting any JS-errors?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your JSON as well?

Comment: Firebug is displaying "object is undefined, length = object.length" for the jQuery script, after the first dropdown box is changed.  No errors on page load.

Comment: Just edited question to include sample JSON output.

Comment: Do you know which row the error occurs on? I've added an answer with a few things you can look at.

Comment: The error you are reporting isn't represented in the code you have shared. THere is no call to the length property of any object. Me thinks the problem is somewhere else in your code. my question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704694/how-to-create-chained-eventhandlers-in-jquery-on-repeated-groups-of-elements) offers a solution to this very scenario.

Comment: This is another way to reach this - http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/dynamic-select-list-jquery-php/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your document-ready looks a bit off, it should either be `$(document).ready(function(){});` or it could be just `$(function(){});`.

Second, you looping over the JSON result looks a bit odd as well. Try something like this instead:

```
$.each(data.subjects, function(i, val){    
   $('select#item_2').append('<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: Made the changes you suggested, but still no go.  Using jQuery 1.7, it says the error is on line 632.

Comment: @Michael Okay, since I don't have all your code, I don't know which row that is. Can you look it up for me, or highlight it in your code sample?

Comment: @Michael Well, the problem is most likely not in the jQuery file, but when I look at that row in the jQuery source, that is where they declare the each method. That makes me think that it is you loop that is the problem. How come you pass data.subjects into the loop. Does the JSON-result contain more than what you showed me in the example code?

Comment: @Michael If the JSON-result is just what you've showed, then try passing just `data` to the each function, instead of `data.subjects`. If that doesn't help, please do a `console.log(data);` in the success callback, and post what is being logged, so that I know what data contains.