# Multiple, dynamic dropdown list based on user selection

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have read through all the "dynamic multiple dropdown lists" questions here on stackoverflow but could not find what I am looking for.

It's a form for states and cities. User select a state, through ajax I request the cities for that specific state ID.

But, I need to have the two selects already created and displayed (maybe the city select grayed out). An example here [PenskeAutomotive](http://www.penskeautomotive.com/).

What I managed to do so far is to have only the state select and upon the execution of ajax, from the XMLHttp.ResponseText to create the city select. An example here [Dorpdown list example - at bottom of page](http://coursesweb.net/ajax/multiple-select-dropdown-list-ajax_t).

I need to have both selects displayed and then only update the city select with the new values of the XMLHttp.ResponseText.

Can anybody point me to some direction?

UPDATE:

Right after posting I found a question that I have not read before. Went into it and I may have found my direction. I am just trying that right now. It's jQuery/Ajax. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749326/how-to-populate-second-dropdown-based-on-selection-of-first-dropdown-using-jquer?rq=1)

Comment: ◄ go that way.. just kidding, can you post what you have?

Comment: Or better yet, JSFiddle part of the demo?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your current code, and what you are having issues with.

Comment: Sorry people. As I say in my update I found that question that lead me exactly where I needed. After a few hours of messing with that code I made it work exactly how I needed. But thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you're having trouble, but to (hopefully) point you in the right direction:

You could have both of your `<select>` elements created on the page, with the City dropdown having the HTML `disabled` attribute, which will gray it out.

The disabled dropdown will have no options, aside from maybe one that says something like "select state."

You'll add an `onchange` event listener to your State dropdown which will perform the AJAX call, and I would recommend you get your response back in [JSON format](http://www.json.org/).

Then you can clear out the options of the next dropdown and create and append the new options from your server, then enable the dropdown.

If you want to provide what you've done so far, I'm sure we can help debug it.

Comment: This is a good approach.  Once you have the list of cities You can use it to populate the second select element and then go from there

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in my site, maybe is usefull for you:

in head:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#select1").change(function(event){
            var id = $("#select1").find(':selected').val();
            $("#select2").load('../scripts/depto.php?id='+id);
        });
    });
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#select2").change(function(event){
            var id = $("#select2").find(':selected').val();
            $("#select3").load('../scripts/municipios.php?id='+id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

and in select:

```
<div class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Pa&iacute;s </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="IDPAIS" id="select1" required>    
            <?
                $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM lista_paises");
                $sql->execute();
                while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo 
                    '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[opcion].'</option>';
                }
            ?> 
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Departamento </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="departamento" id="select2" required></select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Municipio / Ciudad</label>
    <div class='controls'>
        <select name="ciudad" id="select3" required></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the lista_paises.php

```
<?
include('../include/config.php');
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM PAISES);

$respuesta="[";
foreach ($aMunicipios as $muni) {
    $respuesta .="{id:".$muni["id_municipio"].",nombre_municipio:'".$muni["municipio_nombre"]."'},";
    }
$respuesta = substr($respuesta,0,strlen($respuesta)-1);

$respuesta.="]";
echo $respuesta;
}
?>
```

in depto.php

```
<?
include('../include/config.php');
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM lista_estados WHERE relacion = ".$_GET['id']);
$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo 
'<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[opcion1].'</option>';
}
?>
```

in municipios.php(ciudad/city)

```
<?
include('../include/config.php');
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM MUNICIPIOS WHERE relacion1 = ".$_GET['id']);
$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo 
'<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[opcion2].'</option>';
}
?>
```

maybe works for you

Comment: Thanks so much. This is very close to what I found on the question link on my UPDATE.