# Second select load from database after first one is selected

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have 2 `select` items.

In the first one I'm loading the options from a MySQL database table using PHP.

The second one I want to load the fields from another table where for example `category` field equals the value of the item selected on the first tag.

I have no idea about how I can make the second `select` tag load the options dynamically. I know I need to use Ajax I guess.

I've found this, but it doesn't help too much since the options of the first `select` tag depend on what it can find in the database.

```
// Given the options in the first dropdown are: "foo", "bar", and "baz"
var secondData = {
    foo: ['lorem', 'ipsum'],
    bar: [1,2,3],
    baz: []
}
```

Then I need to add a 'change' event to the first dropdown, and given the value of that dropdown, load the contents of the second dropdown with the values contained in the secondData object, but I can't apply this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to populate second dropdown based on selection of first dropdown using jQuery/AJAX and PHP/MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749326/how-to-populate-second-dropdown-based-on-selection-of-first-dropdown-using-jquer)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the values for the second dropdown from a database, then you do need ajax.

See this post:

[Populate dropdown 2 based on selection in dropdown 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924082/dynamic-drop-down-box/16924652#16924652)

A couple of other good posts re the basics of AJAX:

[A simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734395/form-inside-of-load-not-posting-correctly/13734466#13734466)

[More complicated example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887098/two-post-requests-one-after-the-other-second-post-request-doesnt-get-execut/17887642#17887642)