# How to add one more dynamic chained select box to this code

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

I'm using this [plugin](http://css-tricks.com/examples/DynamicDropdown) from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/) for php/mysql/jquery two chained select boxes using PHP, jQuery and Mysql. I'm considering adding an additional box whose choices depend on the first and second box. I've tried to replicate and modify the second half part of getter.php handler and JS code but of course it failed. Does it need some IF statements for the second and third boxes to get it to work?

Getter.php:

```
<?php

$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "localhost";

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$selected = mysql_select_db("dropdownvalues", $dbhandle) or die("Could not select examples");
$choice = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['choice']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM dd_vals WHERE category='$choice'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option>" . $row{'dd_val'} . "</option>";
}
?>
```

Code:

```
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
    $("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="first-choice">
    <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
    <option value="beverages">Beverages</option>
    <option value="snacks">Snacks</option>
</select>

<br />

<select id="second-choice">
    <option>Please choose from above</option>
</select>
```

Comment: do you mean having three select boxes one after another, and changing the first one will fill up the second one, and the second one onchange will fill up the  third one ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Yes, that's what I'm trying to say. I've created an additional column in the table, and I want the third box to pull data from it based on what I've chosen in the first and second box.

Comment: @RedGiant : I hope this following link help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8749326/2806972

Answer (score 0):

You can try this type of method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#first-choice").change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : 'getter.php',
            data : {
                choice : value
            },
            success : function(data){
                $('#second-choice').html(data); 
                $('#third-choice').html('<option>Select second option</option>');   
            }
        })
    });
    $("#second-choice").change(function() {
        var first_value = $("#first-choice").val();
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : 'getter2.php',
            data : {
                choice : first_value,
                second : value
            },
            success : function(data){
                $('#third-choice').html(data);  
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I've added a third box and copied your method. It gets the third box to respond but it fails to retrieve data from sql. I'd like to see what modifications are needed in the php file.

Comment: Please look my updated jquery. you can select from database with 2 `get` data. `choice` and `second`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the following `HTML` code is written in `page.php`

```
<div class="result"></div>
<select id="first-choice">
    <option selected value="-1">Please Select</option>
    <option value="beverages">Beverages</option>
    <option value="snacks">Snacks</option>
</select>

<br />

<select id="second-choice">
    <option value="-1">Please Select</option>
</select>

<select id="third-choice">
    <option value="-1">Please Select</option>
</select>
```

in `page.php` , you also have the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#first-choice").change(function(){


    var first-choice=$.trim($("#first-choice").val());

    if(first-choice==-1){


    $(".result").html('<span>first choice not selected</span>');


    }else{

    $(".result").html('<span>Please wait...</span>');

    $.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    url:"page_1.php",
    data:"first_choice="+first-choice,
    success:function(response){

    $("#second-choice").html(response);

    $(".result").html('');

    },
    error:function(response){


    alert("error occurred");




 }
```

});

```
}


});



});



</script>
```

in `page_1.php` , you have :

```
    <?php

    $first_choice = trim($_POST['first_choice']);

     $username = "username";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "localhost";

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$selected = mysql_select_db("dropdownvalues", $dbhandle) or die("Could not select examples");
//    $choice = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['choice']);

//$query = "SELECT * FROM dd_vals WHERE category='$choice'"; **Write it as you need**

$result = mysql_query($query);

echo '    <option selected value="-1">Please Select</option>'; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">' . trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($row['dd_val'])) . '</option>';
}

    ?>











    $(document).ready(function(){
```

$("#second-choice").change(function(){

```
var first_choice=  $.trim($("#first-choice").val());    
var second-choice= $.trim($("#second-choice").val());

    $(".result").html('<span>Please wait...</span>');

          $.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    url:"page_2.php",
    data:"first_choice="+first-choice+"&second_choice="+second-choice,
    success:function(response){

    $("#third-choice").html(response);

    $(".result").html('');

    },
    error:function(response){


    alert("error occurred");


    }

    });


    });


    });
```

in `page_2.php` you have :

```
<?php
$second_choice=trim($_POST['second_choice']);

//now do as you did in page_1.php to fetch data from DB and echo them as `options`s


?>
```

Do not forget to use the `<script/>` tag when you use javascript. As to the `php` code used, I copied (not tested ) your code with modification.

**EDIT:**

added an `&` before `second_choice="+second-choice,`

Comment: I did as you told, but it seems that the code isn't firing up the  page_1.php and page_2.php. No data in the second box is pulled.

Comment: Do you get any error in the browser console (i.e. Firebug console)?