# Query MySQL database using value from a dropdown, then populate a text field with the result without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a dropdown in a form that is being populated with a list of employees from a table called 'employees' in a MySQL database (employee_id, fname, lname). This is working just fine.

What I need to do next is when an employee is selected from the dropdown, I need to query the employees table to get the employees commission percentage (commission) and then populate another text field in the form with that value.

The issue is that i need to do this without reloading the page. I have been searching Google and it looks like i need to use AJAX and JavaScript. to accomplish this, my problem is that I don't know a thing about AJAX, though i do have some experience with java script.

The employees table looks like this:
employee_id
fname
lname
commission

Below is what I have so far.

```
<?php
// DB connection
require_once('Connections/freight.php');

// get employee list for dropdown
$query_rsEmployeeList = "SELECT employee_id, fname, lname FROM employees ORDER BY fname ASC";
$rsEmployeeList = mysqli_query($con, $query_rsEmployeeList) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row_rsEmployeeList = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsEmployeeList);
$totalRows_rsEmployeeList = mysqli_num_rows($rsEmployeeList);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frmAddAgents" name="frmAddAgents" method="post" action="">
    Agent:
    <select name="employee_id" id="employee_id">
        <option selected="selected" value="">- select agent -</option>
        <?php do { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row_rsEmployeeList['employee_id']?>"><?php echo $row_rsEmployeeList['fname']?> <?php echo $row_rsEmployeeList['lname']?></option>
        <?php
        } while ($row_rsEmployeeList = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsEmployeeList));
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($rsEmployeeList);
        if($rows > 0) {
          mysqli_data_seek($rsEmployeeList, 0);
          $row_rsEmployeeList = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsEmployeeList);
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    Commision: 
    <input name="commission" type="text" id="commission" size="3" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add Agent To Load" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysqli_free_result($rsEmployeeList);
?>
```

---

OK, I looked at the other question and although it is different, I tried to change the code around to make it work, but i'm not having any luck. When I select an item from the dropdown, nothing happens. Below is the updated code. I'm not sure if i'm on the right path or not.

```
<?php
// DB connection
require_once('Connections/freight.php');

// get employee list for dropdown
$query_rsEmployeeList = "SELECT employee_id, fname, lname FROM employees ORDER BY fname ASC";
$rsEmployeeList = mysqli_query($con, $query_rsEmployeeList) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row_rsEmployeeList = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsEmployeeList);
$totalRows_rsEmployeeList = mysqli_num_rows($rsEmployeeList);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>demo</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#employee_id").change(function () {   

      var employee_id = $(this).val();

       $.ajax({
            type: "GET", 
            url: "ajax.php", 
            data: {employee_id: employee_id},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                var comm = data[0].commission;
                $('#commission').empty(); 
                $('#commission').append('<option value="0">0.00</option>');         
                $('#commission').append('<option value="' + comm + '">' + comm + '</option>');
                $('#commission').focus();
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#commission').empty();
                $('#commission').append('<option value="0">Loading...</option>');
            },
            error: function(){
                $('#commission').empty();
                $('#commission').append('<option value="0.00">0.00</option>');
            }
        })  

    }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frmAddAgents" name="frmAddAgents" method="post" action="">
    Agent:
    <select name="employee_id" id="employee_id">
        <option selected="selected" value="">- select agent -</option>
        <?php do { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row_rsEmployeeList['employee_id']?>"><?php echo $row_rsEmployeeList['fname']?> <?php echo $row_rsEmployeeList['lname']?></option>
        <?php
        } while ($row_rsEmployeeList = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsEmployeeList));
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($rsEmployeeList);
        if($rows > 0) {
          mysqli_data_seek($rsEmployeeList, 0);
          $row_rsEmployeeList = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsEmployeeList);
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    Commision: 
    <input name="commission" type="text" id="commission" size="3" />%
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add Agent To Load" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
mysqli_free_result($rsEmployeeList);
?>
```

Here is the test2.php file that ajax is using to query the database

```
<?php
// DB connection
require_once('Connections/freight.php');

if (isset($_GET['employee_id'])) {   
    $employee_id = $_GET['employee_id'];
    $return_arr = array();
    $result = $con->query ("SELECT commission FROM employees WHERE employee_id = $employee_id");   

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $row_array = array("commission" => $row['commission']); 
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);     
    }
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to populate second dropdown based on selection of first dropdown using jQuery/AJAX and PHP/MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749326/how-to-populate-second-dropdown-based-on-selection-of-first-dropdown-using-jquer)

Comment: Its not quite the same, but i still took a stab at it. I changed the code up a little to try and get it to work, but i'm still not having any luck. Currently when I select an item form the dropdown, nothing happens. I added the updated code to my original post

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is the final code.

test.php

```
<?php
// DB connection
require_once('Connections/freight.php');

// get employee list for dropdown
$query_rsEmployeeList = "SELECT employee_id, fname, lname FROM employees ORDER BY fname ASC";
$rsEmployeeList = mysqli_query($con, $query_rsEmployeeList) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row_rsEmployeeList = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsEmployeeList);
$totalRows_rsEmployeeList = mysqli_num_rows($rsEmployeeList);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>demo</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#employee_id").change(function () {   

      var employee_id = $(this).val();

       $.ajax({
            type: "GET", 
            url: "ajax.php", 
            data: {employee_id: employee_id},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                var comm = data[0].commission;
                $('#commission').empty(); 
                $('#commission').val(comm);
                $('#commission').focus();
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#commission').empty();
                $('#commission').val('0.00');
            },
            error: function(){
                $('#commission').empty();
                $('#commission').val('0.00');
            }
        })  

    }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frmAddAgents" name="frmAddAgents" method="post" action="">
    Agent:
    <select name="employee_id" id="employee_id">
        <option selected="selected" value="">- select agent -</option>
        <?php do { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row_rsEmployeeList['employee_id']?>"><?php echo $row_rsEmployeeList['fname']?> <?php echo $row_rsEmployeeList['lname']?></option>
        <?php
        } while ($row_rsEmployeeList = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsEmployeeList));
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($rsEmployeeList);
        if($rows > 0) {
          mysqli_data_seek($rsEmployeeList, 0);
          $row_rsEmployeeList = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsEmployeeList);
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    Commision: 
    <input name="commission" type="text" id="commission" size="3" />%
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add Agent To Load" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
mysqli_free_result($rsEmployeeList);
?>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
// DB connection
require_once('Connections/freight.php');

if (isset($_GET['employee_id'])) {   
    $employee_id = $_GET['employee_id'];
    $return_arr = array();
    $result = $con->query ("SELECT commission FROM employees WHERE employee_id = $employee_id");   

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $row_array = array("commission" => $row['commission']); 
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);     
    }
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>
```