# Using the selected option of first dynamic dropdown to display the second dynamic dropdown using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have been trying to figure out how to create dynamic dependent drop-downs.
 I have seen examples on creating dependent drop-downs which are not populated from a MySQL table.
 That is, the options for the drop-down are entered manually by us without taking from the MySQL database.

It would be really great if anyone can help me in displaying the second dynamic drop-down list based on the option selected in the first dynamic drop-down using Ajax, PHP, jQuery and MySQL.
 I have been working on this since a week but couldn't figure out.
Please find my html code below:

**javascript:**

```
function showForm() {
    var selopt = document.getElementById("opts").value;
    if (selopt == 1) {
        document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (selopt == 2) {
        document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
    <?php
//config.php has the connection to my database and the MySQL query that is needed to fill in the department dropdown dynamically.
        require("config.php");
        echo '<select id="opts" onchange="showForm()">';
// Creating the dynamic department dropdown by using data in MySQL table.
        foreach($rowDept as $row) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['Department'] ."'>" . $row['Department'] ."</option>";
        }
        echo "<option value = 1>ALL DEPARTMENTS</option>";
        echo "<option value = 2>NULL</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        ?>

    <!--<div id="f1" style="display:none">-->
        <div id="f1" style="display:none">
        <form name="form1">
            <select id="opts" onchange="showForm()">
                <option value="1">Option 1A</option>
                <option value="2">Option 1B</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!--<div id="f2" style="display:none">-->
        <div id="f2" style="display:none">
        <form name="form2">
            <select id="opts" onchange="showForm()">
                <option value="1">Option 2A</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2B</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
```

In the above code, as I am providing the options "NULL" and "ALL DEPARTMENTS" manually. So, I have assigned values to them and used those values in the javascript code to display the appropriate child dropdown. But, if you see in the case of department dropdown where the dropdown is being filled dynamically from the MySQL table how to provide the value of the option that has been selected by the user in the javascript code to display the appropriate child dropdown?

Comment: Do you have any code of trying?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate second dropdown based on selection of first dropdown using jQuery/AJAX and PHP/MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749326/how-to-populate-second-dropdown-based-on-selection-of-first-dropdown-using-jquer)

Comment: Working on it for a week should have definitely yielded some attempts at code you can share.