# Handling dynamic dropdown box using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to create a dynamic drop down box that accesses MySQL once a selection has been made. The second box depends on the first box selection. I am not too familiar with javascript but I came across some code that seemed to be what I was looking for but is not executing and I don't know why. The first part of the code is the option fields with the javascript and the second part is the dynamicdd.php. Any help would be great. Thank you.

```
<tr>
    <td>Country:  </td>
    <td>
        <select name="Countrybox" onchange="getlocation(this.value)">
            <option value="none"> Please Select </option>

            <?php
              $qry2 = "Select Country from Locations";
              $populate = mysqli_query($conn, $qry2);

              while ($run = mysqli_fetch_assoc($populate)){
                echo "<option value='".$run['Country']."'>".$run['Country']."</option>";
              }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td>Location:</td>
    <td>
        <select name="Locationbox" id="locationbycountry">
            <option> Select Above First </option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getlocation(locationarea) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "dynamicdd.php";
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('SearchValue', locationarea);
    xhttp.open('POST', url, true);
    xhttp.send(data);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("locationbycountry").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

dynamicdd.php

```
<?php

if($_POST['SearchValue']){
  $host = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $db = "Work";

  $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username ,$password, $db);

  $choice = $_POST['SearchValue'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE Country = '$choice'";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<option value='".$row['Location']."'>".$row['Location']."</option>";
  }

}


 ?>
```

Comment: Are you willing to consider a jQuery replacement for <select> boxes?

Comment: I'm willing to consider any help

Comment: Did you try to debug? Do you have enabled javascript in browser? Put some alerts in function getlocation to see is it working. Put some loggint into dynamicdd.php  to see is it working.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with javascript to know how to test for errors

Comment: jQuery introduces a host of other issues so if you're not familiar with javascript, this may be a rough way to go. But Select2 is a FANTASTIC replacement option for the select box, and you can do a lot with dynamic data sources such as what you're wanting to do above. Check it out: https://select2.org/data-sources/formats

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate second dropdown based on selection of first dropdown using jQuery/AJAX and PHP/MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749326/how-to-populate-second-dropdown-based-on-selection-of-first-dropdown-using-jquer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change javascript part with this (it will trow messagebox and you will see is script fail before end):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function getlocation(locationarea) {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = "dynamicdd.php";
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append('SearchValue', locationarea);
                xhttp.open('POST', url, true);
                xhttp.send(data);
                alert("*step 1*");
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        alert("*step 2*");
                        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                        alert("*step 3*");
                        alert(xhttp.responseText);
document.getElementById("locationbycountry").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                alert("*step 4*");
                }
    </script>





<?php
    if($_POST['SearchValue']){
      $host = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "";
      $db = "";

      $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username ,$password, $db);

      $choice = $_POST['SearchValue'];

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE country = '$choice'";

      echo $sql;
    }
    else {
       echo "value is not posted";
    }
?>
```

Comment: It gave me a notification saying "localhost says step 1" all the way through 10 then went back to 8 and 9.

Comment: try copy again. A put alert for display result from php. With this alert we will see if there has any result. One more question.After you got step 9 alert did you second listbox was empy or it is still containing text "Select Above First"?

Comment: The second select box goes empty after step 9. After looking again it actually skips 9 the first time to step 10 then goes back to 8 then 9.

Comment: i ti ok to show 8 and 9 after 10. Try now change php with script which i paste. This will display only select in alert. After you got this select we well se is it correct. Btw. secont listbox is empty because php didn't retur data to display. Maybe select return 0 record.

Comment: It also doesnt echo the $sql

Comment: changing my code to the new one you sent i got a parse error saying: syntax error, unexpected '&quot;'&gt;&quot;' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in dynamicdd.php on line 18

Comment: my php code seems ok though i dont see any syntax errors.. line 18 is the echo line within the while loop

Comment: Ok its now giving alert of localhost says 'select * from locations where country = 'USA'' this seems like a good sign. So is my loop bad?

Comment: if you execute this select on database, did you get any record?

Comment: Its working! I rewrote my while loop and i guess there was something i did different than my original loop. Thank you for your help! Its been really appreciative and I'll pass it on

Comment: Ok. I'm glad that you resolve your problem Can you change code in you question or in my so answer so i is correct and mark as resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is formed well enough, but you have errors in your PHP script. Try the following code which corrects some simple typos:

```
<?php
if($_POST['SearchValue']){
  $host = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $db = "";

  $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username ,$password, $db);

  $choice = $_POST['SearchValue'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE country = '$choice'";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('error');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo "<option value='".$row['location']."'> ".$row['location']." </option>";

    }
}
?>
```

Also, please be sure to look more into Select2, which is a really well-supported replacement for standard select boxes. https://select2.org/

Comment: I'll look more into select2 unfortunately the revised php code didn't work. I'm not getting a msyql error so I am assuming it may be the javascript code. I just don't know where something may be wrong

Comment: The above PHP code works and is usable code so if it's not working for you, I would check your $conn parameters to be sure you're using the correct host, username, password, and db for your development environment. Is that where things are possibly going sideways?

Comment: Also, your field name above in the <option> tag is 'location' but other places you're capitalizing your field names (i.e., "Country" and "Locations"). Be sure when invoking a db name from PHP, your syntax matches the data exactly. MySQL queries do not need the same precision but PHP won't match it otherwise.

Comment: The parameters should be good. Its the same ones ive been using on all my other pages. I left out my dbname here but its in my code.