# Pass a JavaScript Variable to PHP for POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu

I have 2 dropdown menus. I want to dynamically populate second dropdown based on the first one. When changing the value in first dropdown, it has to pass the selected value to an invisible php array to update it. So here is the problem: passing the js variable(strUser) to php {{ the php var }} (used {{}} only to make it more simple to see).

```
    <form class="formatted-form" action="" method="POST">
        <div class="message">
            <?php ThemexInterface::renderMessages(isset($_POST['success'])?$_POST['success']:false); ?>
        </div>
        <table class="profile-fields">
            <tbody>
                <?php if(!ThemexCore::checkOption('user_location')) { ?>
                <tr style="display: none">
                    <th><?php _e('Hidden Country', 'lovestory'); ?></th>
                    <td>
                        <div class="select-field">
                            <span></span>
                            <?php 
                            echo ThemexInterface::renderOption(array(
                                'id' => 'country',
                                'type' => 'select',
                                'options' => array_merge(array('-' => '&ndash;'), ThemexCore::$components['countries']),
                                'value' => !empty(ThemexUser::$data['user']['profile']['country'])?{{ThemexUser::$data['user']['profile']['country']}}-this should be replaced with the strUser variable we get in js :null,
                                'wrap' => false,                
                            ));
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                

                <tr>
                    <th><?php _e('Visible_Country', 'lovestory'); ?></th>
                    <td>
                    
                            <span>
                            <?php
                                $post_ids2 = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT DISTINCT country FROM countries" );
                                echo "<SELECT id=tara_1 onChange='reload()' >";
                                foreach ($post_ids2 as $value){
                                    echo "<option value=$value </option>";
                                    echo $value;
                                }echo "</select>";
                                ?>
                            </span>
                    
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <script>
                function reload(){
                    var e = document.getElementById("tara_1");
                    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
                        }</script>
            
                <tr>
                    <th><?php _e('City', 'lovestory'); ?></th>
                    <td>
                            <span>
                            <?php
                                global  $wpdb;
                         $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT city FROM countries WHERE tara='".ThemexUser::$data['user']['profile']['country']."'" );
                                
                                
                                echo "<SELECT id=tara_1 name=cities>";
                                foreach ($post_ids as $value){
                                    echo "<option value=$value </option>";
                                    echo $value;
                                }echo "</select>";
                                ?>
                            </span>
                    
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php
                ThemexForm::renderData('profile', array(
                    'edit' =>  true,
                    'before_title' => '<tr><th>',
                    'after_title' => '</th>',
                    'before_content' => '<td>',
                    'after_content' => '</td></tr>',
                ), ThemexUser::$data['user']['profile']);
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <a href="#" class="button submit-button"><?php _e('Save Changes', 'lovestory'); ?></a>
        
        <input type="hidden" name="update" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_action" value="update_profile" />
        <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce(THEMEX_PREFIX.'nonce'); ?>" />
    </form>
```

I know php is server-side and js works on client-side, that's why i am confused on how could i dynamically refresh the second dropdown AND pass the value selected by user to PHP POST. I am new to PHP and JS so please be kind, i would appreciate any hint on how I should approch the problem. In the end i want it to behave like this:
Dropdown1 selected>Italy, Dropdown2 > {gets populated with italian cities from database}
Dropdown1 selected>France, Dropdown2 > {gets populated with frech cities from database}

Well, the real problem is passing JS to PHP- which i think is the wrong approach.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is _AJAX_.

Comment: All the code should be rewrited in for AJAX or only a specific part?

Comment: Javascript: capture change in dropdown 1. Javascript: send value trough ajax. PHP: receive value, create content of dropdown 2, send back to browser. Javascript: put received dropdown in place.

Comment: A plan of action. Thanks, you just saved me a few hours.

Comment: If you're using jquery: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8749326/1685196)